# How to access a file or directory from another server without copying it over?

Tags: linux, ssh, security, files, networking

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I have my reasons for wanting to do this.
I am looking for a way to possibly access directories that are dependencies without actually having to copy them to my active server. Is there a known way of doing this?

Example:

Application A requires Tools A.
Tools A exists on Server1. Application A is running on Server2. 
Tools A is extremely large, or secured on Server1, and Server2 is being used by a novice user who could possibly be insecure or doesn't want a large directory copied over.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close on this - as it stands this is *way* to broad. Some utilities can be mounted and run over SSH, others can't.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is probably network filesystem. To name a few:

- sshfs
- NFS
- CIFS
- ...

Each has its qualities and issuers, so you'd better be careful before using one in production. NFS has quite probably better reputation. Of course, because data is remote, performance will suffer.

Happy mounting !

Comment: Mmm, NFS... for all your not-working file system needs! :)